# Getting Hadoop Job tracker Metrics in JSON

Tags: apache, hadoop

I am looking for a way to list all of the `JobTracker` and `TaskTracker` details in `JSON` format. When I try `http://[myjobtrackermachine]:50030/metrics?format=json`, I get back an empty `JSON` string (though there are a lot of details present in the UI).

What am I missing?

Comment: I see the entire data when I do the same. Do you get any data when you perform http://[myjobtrackermachine]:50030/metrics

Answer (score 0):

From some experience with working with json and java api's you may be missing a provider for json, probably a library like jackson or gson may be required to be in the class path. These libraries can use reflection on pojo's to convert them to json. Even if this is not a rest api I am sure it relies on some external json library. Hope this helps.

I found a couple of references that point to hadoop using the jackson api, so my guess is that this may be your problem.
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cdh-user/PieR2X77X90